# Custom Underline css on popup

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

In [my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-5tnmj?file=/src/App.vue), I have 2 questions:

1. how can I make custom underline css like this UI image below file name and below trash icon? I have used `text-decoration:none` but not as good as the UI.
2. How can I make an url background center and how can I make input button to show only text 'Add Image' like the UI? I have used the `url` in the `background-image` and also used `display:none` for `input` type but it didn't work in the codesandbox

Notes: I put all the code in the codesandbox so that this page is not too long and if you want to run the code please click `Open In New Window` below `sign in` button on the codesandbox menu

[image: popup UI]

Answer (score 1):

Add below CSS to get the result the same as the UI image is attached.

```
  .upload-box{
    background-image: url(ADD_IMAGE_URL);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}


 .upload-box input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
```

}